# KivyMD NavigationDrawerIconButtons not appearing

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, material-design

Newbie here so, I apologize if the idea I'm trying out is a bit out of order.

So, I'm trying to make an app using KivyMD and I'm already past the part where you can unlock the app and then get to the Screen that contains the Navigation Drawer. However, since (unlike the example given for NavigationDrawer app here https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki/Components-Navigation-Drawer where the NavigationDrawer is the actual root of the MDApp class) my app starts with an "unlock" screen and only after it gets unlocked, the screen containing the NavigationDrawer and the main screen (for the app's content) appears. 
My problem is that I can't (or most probably: I don't know how to) add a list of options under the NavigationDrawer. Below is my actual code and I am having a hard time figuring out where to put this part so it works whenever the NavigationDrawer's opened:

```
def on_start(self):
    for items in {
        "home-circle-outline": "Home",
        "update": "Check for Update",
        "settings-outline": "Settings",
        "exit-to-app": "Exit",
    }.items():
        self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.box_item.add_widget(
            NavigationItem(
                text=items[1],
                icon=items[0],
            )
        )
```

So, I have the NavigationDrawer on another screen (not the root) and it seems like I will have to make some modifications on this part:

```
`self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.box_item.add_widget(
                NavigationItem(
                    text=items[1],
                    icon=items[0],
                )
            )`
```

If my .py code for the app is the one below, where should I put the code block mentioned above (the one for adding clickable options inside the NavigationDrawer)?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBody, OneLineAvatarListItem
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivy.uix.image import Image



loginscreen_kv = '''

#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

LoginScreen:
    scr_mngr: scr_mngr
    ScreenManager:
        id: scr_mngr
        screen1: screen1
        transition: FadeTransition()
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: "deku_blur30.png"
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        Screen:
            id: screen1
            name: 'screen1'
            username: username
            password: password

            MDCard:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: dp(520), dp(340)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    padding: dp(20)
                    spacing:20

                    MDLabel:
                        markup: True
                        text: '[b]Creator Login Credentials[/b] \\n [i]...so you can use the app[/i]'
                        theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: dp(36)

                    MDSeparator:
                        height: dp(5)

                    MDTextField:
                        id: username
                        hint_text: "Username "
                        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"

                    MDTextField:
                        id: password
                        hint_text: "Password "
                        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                        password: True

                    MDFlatButton:
                        text: "Unlock the App"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                        on_release: root.check_data_login()
        MainAppScr:


<MainAppScr>:
    name: 'main_app_scr'
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager1

        Screen:
            name: 'screen1'

            NavigationLayout:
                ScreenManager:
                    id: screen_manager2
                    transition: FadeTransition()
                    Screen:
                        FloatLayout:
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            canvas:
                                Rectangle:
                                    source: "./dualface.jpeg"
                                    size: self.size
                                    pos: self.pos
                            MDToolbar:
                                title: "HeroAca"
                                background_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
                                pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                                elevation: 10
                                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]


                MDNavigationDrawer:
                    id: nav_drawer
                    # find auto-dismiss function
                    auto_dismiss: True
                    ContentNavigationDrawer:
                        id: content_drawer

# insert NavigationDrawerIconButtons here

<Page2@Screen>:

    name: "screen2"
    FloatLayout:
        size_hint: 0.98, 0.95
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                #source: "./deku.jpg"
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

###

<NavigationItem>:
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    divider: None

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "200dp"

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                Rectangle:
                    #source: './deku.jpg'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            # this is for the logo area of the drawer (inside the FloatLayout)
            BoxLayout:
                id: top_box
                size_hint_y: None
                height: "360dp"
                padding: "10dp"
                x: root.parent.x
                pos_hint: {"top": 1}

                Image:
                    # line below is for reference of how the original example mapped the kivymd logo
                    source: f"{images_path}kivymd_alpha.png"
                    #source: "./deku_transp.png"

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "close"
                x: root.parent.x + dp(10)
                pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                on_release: root.parent.toggle_nav_drawer()

            MDLabel:
                markup: True
                text: "[b]Teppy's Test App[/b]\\nVersion: 0.1"
                pos_hint: {'center_y': .5}
                pos_hint: {'top': .75}
                x: root.parent.x + dp(10)
                y: root.height - top_box.height + dp(10)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

        ScrollView:
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}

            GridLayout:
                id: box_item
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
'''



class MainAppScr(Screen):
    pass

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class NavigationItem(OneLineAvatarListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class LoginScreen(FloatLayout):

    scr_mngr = ObjectProperty(None)

    def check_data_login(self):
        username = self.scr_mngr.screen1.username.text
        password = self.scr_mngr.screen1.password.text

        print(username)
        print(password)

        if username == "" and password == "": # set a username and pw to unlock the app
            self.change_screen("main_app_scr")

    def change_screen(self, screen, *args):
        self.scr_mngr.current = screen



class MyHeroAcademia(MDApp):
    title = "MyHeroAcademia App"
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.primary_accent = "BlueGray"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(loginscreen_kv)


# find a way to get this to the nav drawer
"""
    def on_start(self):
        for items in {
            "home-circle-outline": "Home",
            "update": "Check for Update",
            "settings-outline": "Settings",
            "exit-to-app": "Exit",
        }.items():
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.box_item.add_widget(
                NavigationItem(
                    text=items[1],
                    icon=items[0],
                )
            )
"""



if __name__ =="__main__":
    MyHeroAcademia().run()
```

In general, I want to make the NavigationDrawer ("MainAppScr" on my code) screen work just like the example on the documentation.
All the help is much appreciated!

Comment: MyHeroAcademia  I see :D

Comment: Lol! And I was hoping I'll be enlightened. :D

Comment: sorry can't help you :/

Comment: no worries! I already found out a way though I had to totally create it from scratch. :)